# Avoid Auto restart server meteor when file change

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

when i save any change in file even inserting a space, meteor restart immediately, so cpu always run in high frequency. How I can fix it ? Any one have similar issues?

Comment: Just use `meteor --once` to avoid watching for file changes.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. It works now.

Comment: Is there a plugin, that makes the reload more efficient? So that a text change in the html does not require a full reload on the browser side?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable HCP (hot code push) by adding this anywhere in your client code:

```
Meteor._reload.onMigrate(function() {
  return [false];
});
```

After doing that, you'll need to manually refresh the page in order to see any new changes.